# Value of type '[UILabel]' has no member 'text'

Tags: ios, swift

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  FunFacts
//
//  Created by Moises Miguel Hernandez on 11/27/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Moises Miguel Hernandez. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var funFactLabel: [UILabel]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        funFactLabel.text = "An Interesting Fact"

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }//end of recive memory warning


}//end of viewController
```

I am using Xcode and Swift 4. I am just starting out and taking a course from team treehouse.

In the video tutorial they easily did the `funFactLabel.text = "Some Fun fact"`

When I try to do that it gives me this error:

> Value of type '[UILabel]' has no member 'text'

I don't think I am doing anything wrong. I just want to change the text of the label to say: "Some Fun Fact".

Comment: do you really think funcFactLabel is a text label?

Comment: why array of labels  `[UILabel]!` ?? it should be `IBOutlet var funFactLabel: UILabel!`. `IBOutlet` can't be array.

Comment: [Label] this is an array of UILabel. You most probably have dragged IBOutlet collection from your storyboard to ViewController file. Drag and drop IBOutet instead. It will create an outlet for UILabel.

Comment: @Bilal `IBOutlet` can be array if it is collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `[UILabel]` is an array of UILabels.
Everything in braces `[]` is an array. So you could have an array of strings: `[String]`

Just change the type to a plain `UILabel` like so:

```
@IBOutlet var funFactLabel: UILabel!
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared `funFactLabel` as an array of labels.

replace the line

```
@IBOutlet var funFactLabel: [UILabel]!
```

by

```
@IBOutlet var funFactLabel: UILabel!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your funFactLabel is an array of UILabel.

Either do this :

```
@IBOutlet var funFactLabel: UILabel!
```

Or this but for this you have to take an array and you have to append your labes in it. You can't make an IBOutlet as an array:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for label in funFactLabel{
           label.text = "An Interesting Fact"
         }


    }
```

**But I why an array of label as IBOutlet ?** Never saw someone doing that. For each label take one IBOutlet.

[image]

Right click on label and Drag Referencing Outlets always, 2nd one. Ignore Course Detail, that's just text for my UILabel.

Comment: Yea I wish I would of saw that? I don't know how it came to be an array because I drag and dropped it into the ViewModel so by default it should have not been an array?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have made an `OutletCollection` If you made an `OutletCollection` it will always an array try to choose only `Outlet`.

See here:

[image]

**OutletCollection**

```
@IBOutlet var funFactLabel: [UILabel]!
```

**Outlet**

```
@IBOutlet var funFactLabel: UILabel!
```